# Multiple Aggregation in SQL

Tags: sql, count, average

```
loan_no   loan_amt   contact date  customer_id  salesman_id
```

I have the following table. I need to somehow get the average of loan_no and the average of loan_amt for the people with more than one loan_no. I need to somehow plug in the avg and count functions.

I am seriously struggling with that. I was also thinking of a pivot function.

I would really appreciate it if someone can suggest a SQL code

My efforts so far:

```
select count (loan_no), tcustomer_id
from table
group by customer_id
having count (loan_no) > 1
```

Now I just do not know how to also include the avg function.

Comment: Please post data as text instead of external images.  Also show us that you tried to solve this yourself by posting whatever queries you tried.

Comment: Please post your data as text. Don't link to an image. Read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question. Then, how far have you got? Have you used `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Please include sample data and desired output in your question [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added how to columns should look like and the code I have written up to now

Comment: The average of `loan_amt` is `AVG(loan_amt)`. The average of `loan_no` is `AVG(loan_no)`. Or do you want something else? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need average Loan_no but you can still get it through -

```
select customer_id, avg(loan_no), avg(loan_amt)
  from (select *, count(*) over(partition by customer_id) cnt
          from table)
 where cnt > 1
 group by customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select avg(num_loans), sum(total) / sum(num_loans)
from (select customer_id, count(*) as num_loans, sum(loan_amt) as total
      from table
      group by customer_id
     ) t 
where num_loans > 1;
```